# String comparison and interning

Tags: java, string, comparison, string-interning

The following code (from an interview) produces an output of `false`, but I believe it should be `true`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    String a = "hello";
    String b = a + "world";
    String c = "helloworld";
    System.out.println(b==c);
}
```

I thought that constant String expressions were interned, and `a + "world"` is a constant, so it should intern `"hello world"`.

Can someone explain why the output is `false`?

Comment: yeah i know == gives you reference equality, .equal() to gives you content equality

Comment: @MihaiChelaru this question is about String interning **not** how to compare Strings.

Comment: @Bohemian Can you explain the answer? I have no idea, since it takes from the string literal pool, with the same hashcode value?

Comment: *while it should be true*: why should it be true? You have two different String instances holding the same value (i.e. the same sequence of characters). So, if you understand how to compare strings, and what `==` does, why do you expect it to be true?

Comment: @Bohemian How do you know?

Comment: @shmosel because was an interview question, obviously around interning. I’ll edit the Q.

Answer (score 2):

Java interns all Strings that are *compile time constants*. However, only Strings declared by concatenating String *literals* are considered a compile time constant and so be interned.

This is because the compiler looks only at the line being compiled, so it has no idea if `a` if a is a constant or not. For example, `a` could be declared as:

```
String a = new Date().toString();
```

Hence, `c` is a different instance of String than `b`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this,

```
String b=a+"world";
```

The compiler chooses a `StringBuilder` based concatenation of `String` objects like so,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a);
sb.append("world"); 
String b = sb.toString();
```

This yields a different reference, hence returning `false` as in your case.

But if you use this,

```
String b="hello"+"world";
```

Then the compiler identifies it as a constant, and both the `b` and `c` variables reference the same literal in the constant pool. Hence it returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign strings like in your example, `a`, `b`, and `c` are separate `String` objects. So when you compare them you get `false` because they are *not the same object*. `==` in Java does not do a character-by-character comparison of the string. That's what `String.equals()` is for.

This is a solid summary to read to understand: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: The question is "Can someone explain the following code?" So I explained why his code behaves as it does. *His* question is not specifically about string interning, and it doesn't mention it at all.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are looking at does an equality comparison between two variables that point to two different string instances, which are diferent objects stored in different places in memory (among other things) and are therefore different even though the string they represent is the same.

To do a string comparison you would need to use

```
stringInstance.equals(anotherStringInstance)
```

If you did something like this

```
String a = "abcde";
String b = a;
```

Then you would get a == b to be true as both variables point to the same object.